# Performing a Sobel test with huge discrepancies between unstandardized coefficients?

Tags: regression, mediation

I have read pretty much everything I can find on performing a Sobel test on the internet however the huge discrepancy in my unstandardized coefficients makes me feel like I am doing something completely wrong (a = 0.000306, SEa = 0.000067, b = 430037.87. SEb = 258407.87). Did I miss a step somewhere? Thank you for any insights.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/7ktbT.png]

Comment: What do you expect us to be able to say without seeing the data?

Comment: I was wondering if simply by looking at that huge discrepancy (a being practically zero and b being in the very high digits) someone could immediately identify that this was incorrect. By your response I sense that this is not the case? There seem to be very few examples of Sobel tests on the internet.

Edit: Unfortunately I do not have the RAW data at this moment and this is all I have at the moment. I may be able to provide more data later. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do a Sobel test for assessing the significance of a mediation, don't do it this procedure is considered old fashioned.

From the [website of Andrew Hayes](http://afhayes.com/spss-sas-and-mplus-macros-and-code.html) (who wrote the SPSS macro for Sobel tests):

> "If you intend to use this macro merely to implement the "Baron and
>   Kenny" steps to mediation analysis or the Sobel test, I advise you
>   against this, for bootstrapping has become one of the more highly
>   recommended approaches for inference about indirect effects."

Instead use the bootstrap approach, either implemented for [SPSS by Hayes](http://afhayes.com/spss-sas-and-mplus-macros-and-code.html), in R or SPSS by [Kristopher Preacher](http://www.quantpsy.org/medn.htm) (Preacher & Hayes have developed most together), or use the R [`mediation`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mediation/index.html) packahe by [Kosuke Imai and colleagues](http://imai.princeton.edu/software/mediation.html).